# Are those with Open Work Permits considered Non-Residents of Canada for the TD1 form?

Tags: income-tax, canada

I arrived in Canada on July 11, 2022, and I have an open work permit that is valid until December 31, 2022. My company has requested that I complete TD1 and TD1ON forms because my employment will begin on September 6th. However, I am confused on what option should be chosen from the below section in the TD1 form

> **Non-residents (Only fill in if you are a non-resident of Canada.)**
>
> As a non-resident of Canada, will 90% or more of your world income be
> included in determining your taxable income earned in Canada in 2022?
>
> ▢ Yes (Fill out the previous page.)
>
> ▢ No (Enter "0" on Line 13, and do not fill in Lines 2 to 12 as you
> are not entitled to the personal tax credits.)
>
> If you are unsure of your residency status, call the international tax
> and non-resident enquiries line at 1-800-959-8281.

I am not sure whether should I choose Yes or No. Am I a non-resident or a resident of Canada because 183 days would not have been finished in the taxation year since the tax year finishes on December 31st and my visa expires a day before that?